# customizing existing rally screens

Tags: rally

I know I can create dashboard widgets for the Rally UI, but is it possible to extend existing screens.

When looking at the user story screen, I want to add an iframe that passes the story id on the query string to pass the data to a third party system and display some associated data for the story.  Is this possible?

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this time we do not support extending our main pages (like the User Story Page). We are currently exploring ways to make our new pages more extendable by our customers.
When we have the details about how that can be done you will be able to find them [here](http://www.rallydev.com/productblog/).